# Gravity Cocos2D?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, gravity

In my game, I am using Cocos2D for the Game part. I am now trying to implement gravity but I am hearing that I have to use Box2D or Chipmunk. I could use those but is there any way to do this in Cocos2D, can anyone share any ideas/code just so I can add some simple gravity using Cocos2D if possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very easy using Box 2d and Chipmunk. Its inbuilt in cocos2d framework. Just when you start with the cocos2d application template(for iOS) select the Box2D/Chipmunk template. Its very easy. 
Inorder to start with some gravity you have to create a world and add gravity vectors to it. You have a very simple and detailed tutorial in 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls

Its a tutorial that teaches you to create a bouncing ball app in Cocos2d Box2d Framework.

Comment: But with such examples, when I want to make ball jump, I apply Impulse or Force which I think is not best way. As the speed of jump while applying Impulse or Force is slow and I am unable to controls this behavior of jump.

Answer (score 2):

First create a CGPoint variable called gravity and set it's x value to 0 and it's y value to some negative number.

```
CGPoint *grav = ccp(0.0f,-9.8f);
```

Then, in your game loop, just use ccSub on each of your sprites positions.

```
sprite.position = ccSub(sprite.position,grav);
```

Comment: This causes my sprite to drop very slowly, especially on iPad

Comment: Does anyone know why this is?